Was ist der Unterscheid zwischen Seminar und Seminarsitzung?
Diese zwei Phrasen habe ich oft in dem Skript meines Studienkollegen gesehen. Aber ich verstehe den Unterschied zwischen den zwei Wörtern nicht gut. Beispiel:

Einige Dozenten verlangen, dass in jeder Seminarsitzung ein Student ein Stundenprotokoll anfertigt und seinen Kommilitonen diese Zusammenfassung zur Verfügung stellt.

Was ist die Signifikanz von Seminarsitzung da oben? Wie würde die Bedeutung sein, falls es Seminar wäre?

Ein Seminar besteht aus vielen Sitzungen, beispielsweise ein ganzes Semester lang, Dienstags um 10:00 Uhr.
Eine Sitzung ist die am 30. 4.
Ändert man im Beispielssatz Seminarsitzung auf Seminar, sind damit eher andere Seminare (zu anderen Themen) gemeint, nicht andere Termine desselben Seminars.
